# Recommended Python design for capturing changes to class members

Tags: python

I'm looking for a design pattern suited to Python that will address the following problem:

Assuming a class `Company` that has a member `employees`, which is a list that will contain any number of `Employee`s.

What I would like to capture is when one of the `Employee`'s member variables (let's say `salary`) changes, that change is reflected in the "owning" `Company` (let's say `total_salary`). Let's also assume that `total_salary` is very expensive to calculate and we only want to do that calculation whenever any employee's salary is changed and not whenever we access it as a property.

```
> c = Company()
> print(c.total_salary)
0
> c.employees.append(Employee())
> print(c.total_salary)
0
c.employees[0].salary = 100 # update total_salary for c now
> print(c.total_salary)
100
```

The obvious way is by making sure that there is a reference from each `Employee` back to its owning `Company`. What I'm curious is whether there is a good way to use a getter, setter or something else in `Company` to ensure that I can capture a `salary` change to any element in `employees`, so that I can immediately update `total_salary`. Crucially, we should avoid this recalculation when another member is updated (such as `name`).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, ....):
        self.employees = []
        self.total_salary = 0

    def add_employe(self, employe):
        self.employees.append(employe)
        self.total_salary += employe.salary

    def remove_employe(self, employe):
        self.employees.remove(employe)
        self.total_salary -= employe.salary

    def update_employe(self, employe):
        for e in self.employees:
            if not employe.id == e.id:
                continue
            e.name = employe.name
            # ... update more data here
            if employe.salary != e.salary: # salary suffered changes, update it
                self.total_salary -= e.salary        # subtract the older
                self.total_salary += employe.salary  # sum up the new
                e.salary = employe.salary            # update it


class Employee:
    _id = itertools.count(start=1)
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.id = next(Employee._id)
        # ...
```

You want update `total_salary` only if the `employe.salary` suffered any changes. The responsible for this is in `update_employe` method.
Also an implementation of some sort of `id` to `Employee` is useful.

Comment: I think your solution would work but don't have a unique `id` that I can rely on to do this kind of iteration through all the `Employee`s. I'd also be worried about it being inefficient when there are many `Employee`s since I'd have to iterate to match `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for getter/setter control, look into Python [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property). You can use this pattern to catch when variables are set, in order to implement the auto-update feature.

Comment: The problem with a property is that the `Company` will not have any idea when _certain_ members of `Employee` have been changed so the `total_salary` may be needlessly recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of reasonable ways to do what you're asking. One is to have the company dynamically compute its totals each time they're requested. The other approach is for the `Employee` to know the company it belongs to, and for it to update the company's totals whenever it's own information changes.

I think the first approach is easier, since the `Employee` instances doesn't need to know anything about the `Company`, and you don't to do anything special when an Employee is updated. The downside is that if you have a company with many employees and request its totals often, it may be slow, since it needs to iterate over all the employees each time. Here's how I'd implement it, using a `property`:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self):
        self.employees = []

    @property
    def total_salary(self):
        return sum(e.salary for e in self.employees)
```

If you go with the second approach, you'd also use a `property`, but you'd put it in the `Employee` class, so it can detect changes being made to the `salary` attribute:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self):
        self.employees = []
        self.total_salary = 0

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, employer):
        self.employer = employer
        self._salary = 0

    @property
    def salary(self):
        return self._salary

    @salary.setter
    def salary(self, value):
        self.employer.total_salary += value - self._salary
        self._salary = value
```

To make this work in a more complicated system, you'd probably want a bunch of other methods, like one that adds an `Employee` with a salary already set to a `Company` (currently you must add the `Employee` to the company first, then update it's salary, or the totals will be wrong).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the computation on each request via a getter because in the question I mentioned that it's very expensive to do this calculation (my `Company` and `Employee` scenario is just an example). I'd also like to avoid the "back reference" even though it's a valid pattern for this kind of problem.

Comment: There's no way to avoid the reference from the `Employee` to the `Company` if the employee or the `company.employees` list can be modified directly (rather than by calling methods on the `Company`). You don't necessarily need to set it up the way I did though, you could write, say, a `Company.add_employee` method that sets the `employee.employer` attribute and adds the employee to the `employees` list in one step (it could also take care of case I mention where the employee's salary has already been set).

Comment: This was more or less my conclusion as well, but I wanted to see if there are some other patterns in Python for dealing with this that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: There's not really any way for an instance to detect modifications to the attributes of its own attributes. I guess you could return a proxy object, instead of a real reference to your attribute (e.g. `Company` could return something other than a list when you look up `employees`), but it would be very awkward, especially when you have many layers of nesting (for your example, you'd need a proxy list, that returns proxy `Employee`s).